# Check if a document in firebase exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, discord.js

I'm coding a discord.js bot and I want to use firestore as the database

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot || message.guild === null) return;
    let guildInfo = firestore.doc(`servers/${message.guild.id}`)
    if (!guildInfo.exist) {
        guildInfo.set({
            prefix: "!",
            logsOn: false,
            logsID: 0,
            welcomeOn: false,
            welcomeID: 0,
            welcomeMessage: "",
            wordFilterOn: false
        })
    }
```

This is the start of my message event, and I want it to check if the document exists and if it doesn't to set the variables as shown above. The issue is that this code seems to run for every message and will overwrite its self
so If I try and change something, the next message it gets reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to note here:

1. `get` and `set` operations are done on doc, in your case `guildInfo` (you receive `TypeError: guildInfo.set is not a function` because you are trying to perform `set` operation on top of `get` rather it should be on doc)
2. `exists` is performed on the object you got.

The code should be (with the support of `async`/`await`)

```
let guildInfo = firestore.doc(`servers/${message.guild.id}`);
let guildDoc = await guildInfo.get();

if (!guildDoc.exists) {
   guildInfo.set( {} // your message here
   );
}
```

To have without the support of `async`/`await` @frank-van-puffelen solution should work, except you might have to change  `!guildDoc.exist` to `!guildDoc.exists`.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the Firestore documentation on [reading a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) you'll see that you need to call `get()` to actually read the document from the database. With that knowledge, the code would become something like this:

```
let guildInfo = await firestore.doc(`servers/${message.guild.id}`).get()
if (!guildInfo.exist) {
  ...
```

---

If your environment doesn't support `async`/`await` the equivalent would be:

```
firestore.doc(`servers/${message.guild.id}`).get().then((guildInfo) => {
  if (!guildInfo.exist) {
    ...
```

Comment: When I try this code above with the additional set code shown in the question, I get the error `TypeError: guildInfo.set is not a function`

Comment: That is correct, as `guildInfo` is a `DocumentSnapshot`, and `set` only exists on a `DocumentReference`. You can do `guildInfo.ref.set(...)`. Please keep the documentation handy when doing this type of work, as I find it much more efficient to navigate the types there: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot